# Looking for enteries which does not begin with a capital letter in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
df = {'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'name': [Zeke,such,a,Maya,Derek,an,the]}
```

By the way, it is a huge dataframe. 
Now I want to find the list of names which are wrong such as "such","a","an","the".
I want to remove them and have a df like:

`df_new= {'id': [1,4,5], 'name': [Zeke,Maya,Derek]}`

I already tried finding each specific wrong name by:

```
df.query('name=="a"')
df1.query('name=="an"')
df1.query('name=="the"')
```

The problem is, I do not know how many different wrong names there exists. The only difference between correct names and wrong names are the first letter (samll or capitalized).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`istitle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.istitle.html) for check first character for uppercase with filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['name'].str.istitle()]
```

Or get first value by indexing and check by [`isupper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isupper.html):

```
df = df[df['name'].str[0].str.isupper()]
```

For better performance it no missing values use list comprehension:

```
df = df[[x.istitle() for x in df['name']]]
df = df[[x[0].isupper() for x in df['name']]]
```

---

```
print (df)

   id   name
0   1   Zeke
3   4   Maya
4   5  Derek
```